# How to return Objects with empty sub Array document if sub Array documents don't satisfy the match condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose is not returning Objects if sub Array documents don't satisfy the match condition in mongoose.

**MongoDB Query:**

```js
db.fruits.aggregate(        
    { $match: { "isActive": true, fruitId: "kipld" } },
    { $unwind: '$types' },
    { $match: { "types.isActive": true } },
    { $group: {
            _id: '$_id', 
            name: {$first: '$name'}, 
            price: { $first: '$price' },
            types : { $push : '$types' }
        }
    },
    { $project: {
            '_id': 1, 
            'name':1, 
            'price': 1, 
            'types': 1,
        }
    }
)
```

**MongoDB Collection:**

```
{
    _id: "abcdefg",
    fruitId: "kipld",
    isActive: true,
    types :[
        {
            name: "Kashmir Apple",
            price: 90,
            isActive: false
        },
        {
            name: "American Apple",
            price: 120,
            isActive: false
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected result will be like:**

```
{
    _id: "abcdefg",
    fruitId: "kipld",
    isActive: true,
    types :[]
}
```

But when I'm running the above query I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Your query says `{ $match: { "types.isActive": true } }`, but the input document has `"tyoes.isActive"` values as `false`. So, no documents get selected.

Comment: That is the expected behavior.

Comment: can I do that to return `EMPTY` array if there are no `true` records present?

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: @Rajath You can. But, not with that query pipeline you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result using the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operator. This just filters all the array elements and returns the array with the matching filter condition. Note the filter is applied to each document's array. So, in your case the `$unwind` and `$group` stages are *not needed* to get the result.

**Sample `fruits` collection:**

```
{
        "_id" : "abcdefg",
        "fruitId" : "kipld",
        "isActive" : true,
        "types" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Kashmir Apple",
                        "price" : 90,
                        "isActive" : false
                },
                {
                        "name" : "American Apple",
                        "price" : 120,
                        "isActive" : false
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "uvwxyz",
        "fruitId" : "kipld",
        "isActive" : true,
        "types" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Kinnaur Apple",
                        "price" : 80,
                        "isActive" : false
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Shimla Apple",
                        "price" : 70,
                        "isActive" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

**Aggregation Query:**

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
  { $match: { "isActive": true, fruitId: "kipld" } },
  { $project: { _id: 1, fruitId: 1, isActive: 1, 
                result_types: { $filter: {
                                   input: "$types",
                                      as: "type",
                                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$type.isActive", true ] }
                                 } 
                             } } 
   }
])
```

**The Output:**

Note the "result_types" empty array where the `types.isActive` values are `false` for all elements of "types" array. Only the elements with a value of `true` are in the result output.

```
{
        "_id" : "abcdefg",
        "fruitId" : "kipld",
        "isActive" : true,
        "result_types" : [ ]
}
{
        "_id" : "uvwxyz",
        "fruitId" : "kipld",
        "isActive" : true,
        "result_types" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Shimla Apple",
                        "price" : 70,
                        "isActive" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, prasad I implemented it in the same way